# Default React Native header not going away on screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a screen that is known as the `Settings Screen` and I don't want the default React Native header to be present on that screen, but it is. Here is the (applicable) code I have for the screen so far:

```
export default class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        address: "",
      }
      this.getStore();
   }

  async getStore() {
    try {
      const secretsInCache = await AsyncStorage.getItem('data');
      const jsonData = JSON.parse(secretsInCache);
      this.setState({address: jsonData.base_info.address});
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <PageTemplate headerText='Settings' navBar='true' needsFocus='More'>
        <View style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', alignItems: 'center'}}>

          <HomeScreenContainer>

            <View style={styles.firstContainerSeperation}>
              <Text style={styles.firstContHeading}>Service Address:</Text>
              <Text style={styles.textInFirstBox}>{this.state.address}</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.straightLine} />

          </HomeScreenContainer>

        </View>
      </PageTemplate>
    );
  }

}
```

And here is the Tab navigator code:

```
const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen,
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode: 'modal'
  }
},
{
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  }
});


const MoreStack = createStackNavigator({
  More: {
    screen: MoreScreen,
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
  },
  SettingsStack
});

MoreStack.navigationOptions = {
  headerVisible: false,
  tabBarVisible: false,
  tabBarLabel: 'More',
  tabBarIcon: <TabBarIcon source={require('../assets/icons/more.png')}/>,
};
```

As you can see, in multiple places I'm declaring the headerMode as either `null` or `none`, but there is still the default header popping up?

**How can I get rid of the default React Native header in my Settings Screen?**

Comment: Yes, it is embedded in the MoreStack navigator. The code has been provided above.

Comment: Is there any reason it's embedded? (instead of side by side with `Settings` on the first call to `createStackNavigator`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: ' ',
        headerBackTitle: ' ',
        headerStyle: {
          elevation: 0,
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
          backgroundColor: colors.white
        }
      }
   }
})
```

And delete this of your `SettingsScreen` class:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to set the `header` on `static navigationOptions` to `null`. I have downloaded the [Playground example](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/master/examples/NavigationPlayground) from React Navigation GitHub project and tested just that. The header disappeared.

Your Tab navigation code should look something like this:

```
const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen
  },
  More: {
    screen: MoreScreen
  },
}, {});

MoreStack.navigationOptions = {
  headerVisible: false,
  tabBarVisible: false,
  tabBarLabel: 'More',
  tabBarIcon: <TabBarIcon source={require('../assets/icons/more.png')}/>,
};
```

Make sure you're not having any real time building problems when you ctrl+s.

Answer (score 0):

try to do in this way

```
`const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
  }, {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  })`

`const MoreStack = createStackNavigator({
  More: { screen: MoreScreen }
  }, {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  })`

`const MainStack = creatSwitchNavigatore({
    SettingsStack : SettingsStack, 
    MoreStack : MoreStack 
})
```